# Is there a way to use an Env Variable from CCRC to a non-interactive trigger?

Tags: triggers, clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I have a (clearcase) preop non-interactive trigger that needs to evaluate an environment variable value (from client side) in order to perform some checks.

Is there a way or w/a to pass such environment variable value from client with CCRC to the trigger, considering it seems to do not work as with dynamic or snapshot view?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am interested in this question.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21266044), no. A non-defined environment variable on the server side might cause the trigger to think it is an interactive one.

> The trigger script was referencing a user defined environment variable which was set on the client but could not be found on the `RWP` web server.
>
> In this example the user defined environment variable `MYCC_TRIGGER_TMP` was set on the client to define an alternate temp directory and is referenced by the trigger script.
>   However, it was not defined on the `RWP` web server.

An example of the full error message:

```
Unable to checkin  "<path to file>"
Error: directory for environmentvariable "MYCC_TRIGGER_TMP" or "TMP" not found
ccweb: Warning: Trigger "ci_pre" has refused to let checkin proceed.
Interactive triggers are not supported in the Web interface.
If the trigger was interactive, it may have failed for that reason.
ccweb: Error: Unable to check in   "<path to file>".
```

---

The article [Writing triggers for the ClearCase Remote Client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207634) confirms that, albeit indirectly.

> Note: Under certain conditions, pre-op triggers will not work (for example, triggers that require specific ClearCase environment variable evaluation).
>
> `CCRC` runs as a client process that sends `RPC` commands to the `CCRC` server, where they are executed by separate `CCRC` server processes.
>   These server processes run under Apache, so the environment variables (**EVs**) will likely be different from those seen in command shell windows during interactive development.
>
> The server config file (`rwp.conf`, `ccrc.conf`) can be modified to add environment variables using the `SetEnv` command.